# GCController framework (OSX) not generating notifications

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, nsnotificationcenter, nsopenglview, gamecontroller

I'm trying to integrate the GCController framework into my project. I'm not so familiar with Objective-C, so please excuse my ignorance around how this is supposed to work.

I have a class that extends NSOpenGLView, which registers observer methods for the various controller notifications, like so:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Do some stuff

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(controllerStateChanged) name:GCControllerDidConnectNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(controllerStateChanged) name:GCControllerDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
}
```

and I've defined a super simple handler as such:

```
- (void)controllerStateChanged {
   NSLog (@"something happened, let's check it out\n");
}
```

Problem is, these events/notifications never seem to fire - and when I inspect [GCController controllers], it's entirely empty.

Of course, it stands to reason that if there are no controllers, there will be no events - so maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Or perhaps, for whatever reason - my controller simply fails to generate the required events  (I'm using a PS4 controller which is registered with the OS, be it wirelessly or via USB, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here).

Is there some other place I need to enable these notifications? Do I need to somehow initialise the GCController framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out that the GCController framework only supports MFi (Made For iPod, Made For iPhone, Made For iPad) controller products.

For anyone looking to support non-MFi controllers, you'll need to interface with the HID via IOKit.  Or use the rather excellent [DDHIDLib](http://www.dribin.org/dave/software/#ddhidlib) instead

Comment: I've put together a framework that wraps GCController, and supports non-MFI controllers using an IOS device as a bridge, in particular iCade controllers.  One advantage is that the controller appears as a MFi controller, so it makes it easy to have a common code base.  It supports all the Apple platforms (iOS, tvOS, OS X and watchOS).  It uses NSNetservice for network communication.  https://github.com/robreuss/VirtualGameController